# Regular expression replace whole words in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an expression like:

```
$x="We have a cat here.";
```

I want to replace "a" with, for example 5, so this should look like:

```
We have 5 cat here. //It doesn't make sense, but it's just an example.
```

I tried simple

```
echo str_replace("a","5",$x);
```

but that returned

```
We h5ve 5 c5t here.
```

Then, I tried

```
echo str_replace(" a "," 5 ",$x);
```

but that didn't do the job for strings like

```
We have a cat here. (A dog actually).
```

I decided to use regex, but Im completely newbie to this, and I don't know how to use any of them...
Well, I'd really appreciate any link to a good tutorial, but I need the answer quite fast...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\b` to demark word boundaries, e.g.

```
$newstring = preg_replace('/\b[Aa]\b/', '5', $string);
```

Comment: Maybe you know any way to make it work for UTF8 characters, like ąęć, and so on? I mean if I replace all occurences of "a" with "x", I have "zapłać" changed to "zapłxć", and I'd like to have it same as original text...

Comment: `/u` modifier will enable unicode: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php  (search for `PCRE_UTF8`).